# How can be possible to be logged-in only on certain sites?

Tags: support, login

I'm using Firefox in general, but just switched to Chrome for test one thing, and noticed that I'm logged-in on MSE and ELL, but not for other sites like enSO and ruSO:

> [image: logged or not]

How this can be possible?

Comment: I've had something similar recently. I'm guessing it's somehow caused by them being on different domains - stackoverflow.com and stackexchange.com .

Comment: Do you have cross-domain cookies enabled in Chrome?

Comment: @animuson how can I check this?

Comment: Settings - Advanced - Privacy and Security - Content Settings - Cookies; There should be an option for "Block third-party cookies" there.

Comment: @animuson blocking is disabled in my case.

Comment: Well, it's certainly possible that the cookies on the other domains have since expired, if you never visited those other domains but continued visiting the stackexchange.com domain. Afaik the cookies are only set once at login time, and have to keep being updated by visiting the other sites over time. So if something caused them to get removed for only one domain, you'd be logged out on only that domain. But there's not really any way to debug why your browser would lose a cookie for a single domain. If you just login again, does it work across all domains as expected?

Comment: @animuson They shouldn't expire on their own - we have checks in place to prevent sessions on the same device to only expire at the same time. (Barring bugs, naturally.)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your recent sessions, I don't really see anything unusual. There is a set from Firefox that refreshed earlier today - both on stackoverflow.com and on stackexchange.com (the domains, not necessarily those specific sites).

As animuson mentioned in the comments, third-party cookies are required for this to work, so browsers like Safari are out of the question. I don't have a good answer here for you for Firefox. Try logging in again and see if it keeps happening?

Comment: This happening again, but now in opposite order: I’m logged in on *.stackoverflow.com, but not for *.stackexchange.com. Now I’m using mobile Safari. Mobile Chrome works as expected (logged in everywhere).

Comment: @alexolut Safari doesn't support third-party cookies. At least, the desktop version doesn't, and as far as I know, the mobile behaves the same way. In other words, logging into one domain and having that propagate to the others we have, regardless of which one you first log into, will never work in that browser. That's by design.